# JsonNode - How to update nested values in array

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind, fasterxml, jsonnode

Apologies, Google tells me there are many similar questions to this already asked on Stack Overflow but I'm struggling to find an answer that works for my situation.

I have a Java application that is using JsonNode for the first time (previously mapped to Java classes but that isn't an option on this occasion).

We retrieve a JSON object from a third party, example JSON below:.

```
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "name",
    "dateCreated": "2023-08-03T09:38:21.221Z",
    "queues": {
      "wait": [
        {
          "criteria": [
            {
              "type": "s",
              "threshold": 20
            }
          ],
          "groups": [
            {
              "id": "123",
              "name": "Group 1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "criteria": [
            {
              "type": "s",
              "threshold": 10
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "criteria": [
            {
              "type": "s",
              "threshold": 30
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "criteria": [
            {
              "type": "s",
              "threshold": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I need to update each 'threshold' value in the wait array and then return the JsonNode to another service.

It's very important I maintain the order of each index in the 'wait' array. Also I can only guarantee that 'threshold' will be within a nested 'criteria' array, I cannot guarantee other values won't be present e.g. the 'groups' array in the example above, but it is important that all fields are maintained and none lost.

I have found out online that JsonNode is immutable and you need to cast to ObjectArray to get the put/set methods, however I can't see how these method work for nested values e.g. I can use it to update 'name' but I am struggling to use it to update anything inside 'queues'.

I have seen some posts regarding ArrayNode but all examples I find regards to replacing an entire array and I only want to update single values inside the array.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectNode` contains put() method, which can change the value of the node. You have to cast the `JsonNode` into `ObjectNode`.

I could accomplish this using the following code. I am assuming that all the threshold values will be set to a fixed value. In my case I'm assuming it is 50:

```
           for (JsonNode node : jsonNode) {
                JsonNode waitNode = node.path("queues").path("wait");
                if (waitNode.isArray()) {
                    for (JsonNode item : waitNode) {
                        ((ObjectNode) item.path("criteria").get(0)).put("threshold", 50);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Print updated JSON node using jsonNode.toPrettyString()
            System.out.println("JSON after Node edit: " + jsonNode.toPrettyString());
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. I was close to this solution but when I was trying to get lower into the json e.g. using item.path() then my ObjectNode was becoming a JsonNode again and I was losing the put method. I can see with your answer where I went wrong (closing bracket for the cast was in the wrong place). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectNode` has methods [`set()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#set(java.lang.String,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)) and [`put()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#put(java.lang.String,%20int)), which mutate the node. You just need to reach that node, cast it and set the value. Example:

```
public class SoMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);
    for (JsonNode node1 : root) {
      for (JsonNode node2 : node1.get("queues").get("wait")) {
        for (JsonNode criteriaNode : node2.get("criteria")) {
//          ((ObjectNode) criteriaNode).set("threshold", new IntNode(111));
          ((ObjectNode) criteriaNode).put("threshold",111);
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(root);
  }
}
```